# How to fix wrong text encoding (ðø)?

Tags: laravel

How to fix text encoding: ðø? I'm using Laravel and MySQL database.

I tried

```
mb_convert_encoding($var,$to,$from);
```

But I don't know encoding from and to.

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong decoding - something like UTF-8 decoded as Windows 1252. I guess it would make sence to read about [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)

Comment: Are you working with existing data that is not encoded in UTF-8? If not, then set your mysql database to UTF8 to ensure you always have the right coding. You shouldn't need to convert, then.

Answer (score 0):

Create the database with UTF-8 encoding like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

If you do this, you should never need to convert anything. To ensure incoming user data has the right coding, make sure to set the encoding in the head tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

If you work with existing data, there is no way around figuring out what encoding it has before converting it with  `mb_convert_encoding`.